# How to execute/call a PHP function via ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a PHP file which consists of a number of functions, and when I tried to call one of them via ajax, it executes all the function on that page.

How can I execute only one function at a time via ajax? I am using simple PHP without class-object pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can pass a parameter in the URL telling the PHP which function you want to execute e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.url.com/file.php?functiontocall=functiona",
    success: function(){
        // Do something
    }
});
```

and on the PHP side

```
if ($_GET["functiontocall"] == "functiona") {
    // Call functiona and output response
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need 2 PHP for this. One with all the functions fileA.php, and the other which you will call through ajax fileB.php. fileB.php should include fileA.php and you can call whichever function you want.

Comment: An other alternative would be to pass some identifier through ajax to fileA.php, and inside fileA.php, have switch-case or if-else statements to call appropriate functions